# How to run master mining node with semi-offline slaves?

Tags: client, network, mining-hardware

**How can I run a master mining node with semi-offline slaves?**

I have a single master node that is fully connected to the internet (bidirectional).

The master node is also connected to thousands of slave nodes that are not connected to the internet, but is connected to the master node (also birectional, but only to/from master, not internet). Having the slave nodes connect to the master to use as a proxy is not a valid solution.

Pictorially:

[image]